# selecting files with regular expression using ido-find-file

Tags: files, ido

With regular `find-file` it's possible to supply `*.[ch]` to open all `.c` or `.h` files in a directory.  `ido-find-file` doesn't seem to support this behavior.

I know I can press <kbd>C-f</kbd> while `ido-find-file` is open to switch back to regular `find-file`, but is there a way to tell `ido` that I always want to use the regular  expression matching?

Help says that <kbd>C-t</kbd> toggles regular expression matching, but it doesn't seem to have any affect to me.

Comment: FWIW, when you use `C-x C-f *.[ch] RET` you are *not* using a *regexp*.  You are using a file **globbing** pattern (see the shell).  And this pattern-matching is only for `RET`, not for completion.  If you want to use regexps for pattern-matching for completion, try [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ido cannot select multiple items. You'll have to use the normal `find-file` or Helm.

On the Emacs wiki there seems to be a gist for multi selecting items in Ido but I'm not sure if it works: http://www.emacswiki.org/InteractivelyDoThings

Comment: `ido-toggle-regexp` *does* work. The problem is that it only allows using regexps to filter candidates, **not** selecting multiple candidates.

Comment: Can you give an example of it working? If I input something like `o.*g` or `org$` in my directory of org files nothing appears.

Comment: Starting with a `default-directory` full of `.c` and `.h` files, try pressing `C-x C-f C-t [ c h ] $` (key presses are separated by spaces here). Once you're done typing `ido` will filter out candidates that don't match. Note that it uses regexps and **not** globbing. Now press `C-t` and it should say "No matches" (assuming that you don't have files with that strange name).

Comment: Ahh, my problem was that you can't do this with `(flx-ido-mode 1)` on.

Comment: @nanny that's the limitation of Ido. You can only open only one file. If you want to open multiple files across your project, consider using `helm-projectile-find-file`. Here is [a demo](http://tuhdo.github.io/static/helm-projectile/helm-projectile-find-files-1.gif): as you see, I opened all marked files and later using `helm-mini` to show all available buffers that were created from multiple-file opening. You can also do the same thing with `helm-find-files`, except for the current directory only (since `helm-find-files` is a replacement for stock `find-file`).